# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'all' was never awaited task(*args, **kwargs) RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, chatbot

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
import telebot


bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')


api_id = id
api_hash = 'hash'
phone = 'input your number phone'

client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
client.start()


@bot.message_handler(commands=['all'])
async def all(message):
    await client.get_participants(message.chat.title)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Please explain how to parse users of the chat in which this 'all' function is called.

RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'all' was never awaited   task(*args, **kwargs) RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

It gives me this error and I don’t know what to do, await seems to work, but I can’t figure out what’s wrong

I was trying to make a telegram bot that would tag all users in the chat. first he must parse their usernames, and then tag each

But at the parsing stage an error occurs and nothing further can be done. How to fix this fragment?